# Windows 11 IKEv2 fails to connect, error code 1931 eventID 20227

Tags: windows, vpn, ipsec, mikrotik, ikev2

1. I have Mikrotik configured for accepting IPSec connections with server certificate and RADIUS auth, SHA1 and so on enabled on Mikrotik side for Windows compatibility.
2. It also configured for L2TP/IPSec, which I used previously for remote work and replaced with IKEv2 now.

Both works fine for everyone, however, it seems that I broke something on my own PC. I accidentally established both L2TP and IKEv2 connection. After that, weird things happen. Both connections fail, error ID is 1931, event ID 20227. Mikrotik tells just connect attemt then killing ike connection (both messages informational). The connection attempt lasts for 60s then fails with the error above.

What I've tested:

1. PolicyAgent and IKEEXT services both working and set to Automatic
2. Just deleting all WAN devices from devmgr doesn't work, just delete and create a connection doesn't work either
3. Delete WAN devices + search devices, delete connection, reboot, create new connection - this works until next reboot
4. Other machines work fine on both Windows 10/11 with current Mikrorik server

The problem first appeared after described action - connecting to both IKEv2 and L2TP tunnel at once, previously all worked fine on this machine too. Not sure about any updates were installed on the machine at the time. The question is - how to achieve a permanent solution of the described problem, since 3rd list item is only partially a solution, because it works only until reboot sadly.